# how to get div's text to a variable

Tags: php, jquery

what I mainly want to do is to get the div's content and pass it in a variable. To explain what I have done until now :

I have my php file that contains the code :

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "...","...") or die("Could not connect to the database.");
    mysql_select_db("...") or die("Could not find database <...>");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM datainput WHERE id>=ALL(SELECT id FROM datainput)") or die("Query could not be executed");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    echo $row['id'];
?>
```

In my index.php file I have written the following script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $("document").ready( function(){
                //setInterval("checkForNewData()", 1000);  //30 Minutes = 1800000 Milliseconds
                checkForNewData();
            });

            function checkForNewData(){
                $("#lastid").load("lastData.php");
                var mydata = $("#lastid").text();
            }  

        </script>
```

In my html tag I have a div with id="lastid".
With the code below :

```
 var mydata = $("#lastid").text();
```

I want to keep the current text of lastid div, so I can later compare it with another.

As I have read here, this should have done mydata="6" (is the current result)?
What am I doing wrong?

Can anyone help? Pleaseee...

Comment: Why not just use the query `SELECT MAX(id) FROM datainput`?

Comment: Also, please describe why it isn't working.

Comment: The fact that you're trying to grab the last id is making me sweat a little. Out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: Just for ur curiosity...I want the last id inserted so if a new insertion happens my data will change. I will get the latest data and "refresh" my page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wait for the load to have finished. This is done by using a `callback` function like so:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        $("document").ready( function(){
            //setInterval("checkForNewData()", 1000);  //30 Minutes = 1800000 Milliseconds
            checkForNewData();
        });

        function checkForNewData(){
            $("#lastid").load("lastData.php", function(){
                var mydata = $("#lastid").text();
            });
        }  

    </script>
```

Please see the jQuery API docs for more information: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Essentially, the second argument of the load function can be a function. If it is, then whatever code is in that function will be executed when the load has completed.

Comment: Well I tried this but when I say alert(mydata) in firebug gives me an error that "mydata is not defined". Will I can to use this var later?

Comment: @OlgaL It's only defined inside the function scope, so you'd need to define `var mydata` outside, and set it inside.

Comment: When you use `var mydata = $("#lastid").text();` the variable `mydata` is scoped to the function that you're using it in. As soon as the function finishes the variable goes away. If you want to access it elsewhere, try doing `mydata = $("#lastid").text();` (Lose the var, this will make it global.)

Comment: RexM mydata = $("#lastid").text(); didn't work. This was my initial question!